# How to append comma one character before where dot exists?

Tags: php, regex

I have this as a string-

```
$String ="A. Bird Blue B. Red Hat C. Purple Dinosaur D. Black hat E. Clean soap";
```

I want this -

```
$output="A. Bird Blue, B. Red Hat, C. Purple Dinosaur, D. Black hat, E. Clean soap";
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Please help me out, I have no clue for this

Comment: I would try a regex in the form `[whitespace][letter][dot]` (that's pseudocode, not a real regex) and replace it with the same using a capturing brackets, with a comma prefix. Can you give it a go? There are plenty of regex testers on the web to try.

Comment: @halfer thanks a lot, I will try it out. if possible can you help me on regex code or any link

Comment: For the avoidance of doubt, the likely reason the question has received downvotes is that we encourage at least some effort on questions prior to asking, even if the code you present does not work. I am not sure why it has garnered two upvotes though! `:-/`. If you can show a (partial) attempt on your next question, it will help avoid downvotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using regex.

```
$String ="A. Bird Blue B. Red Hat C. Purple Dinosaur D. Black hat E. Clean soap";
$regex = '/(\s[A-Z]\.)/';
$Output = preg_replace($regex, ',$1', $String);
echo $Output;
```

**Output:**

```
 A. Bird Blue, B. Red Hat, C. Purple Dinosaur, D. Black hat, E. Clean soap
```

**Regex Explanation:**

```
/(\s[A-Z]\.)/
```

- `\s` match any white space character
- [A-Z] match a single character present in the list below
          A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
- `\.` matches the character `.` literally

The matching is replaced by [**comma + first group `(\s[A-Z]\.)`**].

Comment: Just the answer I had in mind. Whilst this is very helpful, we rather have a culture here of encouraging the OP in each case to make a minimal effort, for their own benefit. The impact of being able to request free code might be, unfortunately, that nothing is learned.